# Configure Karma to which js files to use for coverage

Tags: karma-runner, karma-jasmine, karma-coverage

We have a web app that has unit testing written in Jasmin,
It also uses Karma to run the tests on the build server and we also have SONR that shows the report and the nit test coverage.
I want to specify to Karma which files should be testes and should be reported as have unit tests and on which percentage.

how and where do I configure this?